# There is no localize Message appears when logging without email and password

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with my application. When logging in without email and password there is no localize Message appears and returns to the previous screen. How can I solve it?

this code for the login button:

```
login.setOnClickListener {
           val email = etEmail.text.toString()
           val pass = etPass.text.toString()
           auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
               .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                   if (task.isSuccessful && auth.currentUser!!.isEmailVerified) {
                      Toast.makeText(this,"Successful Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       
                   }

                   else if (!auth.currentUser!!.isEmailVerified)
                       Toast.makeText(this,"Check your email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                   else
                       Toast.makeText(this,"${task.exception?.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }

       }
```

Comment: Then what does `Toast.makeText(this,"${task.exception?.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` display?

Comment: its just works if the mail or password is incorrect , but if the email or password or both of them is empty don't work and and return to previous screen.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: when I login with incorrect email or password there is a localized Message appears, but if I let email or password empty and  pressed login there is no localize Message appear and return to pervious screen. hope that will be helpful to you.
Thank you,

Comment: Why would you let email or password empty?

Comment: I try it , user may do it accidentally ,, I want it be required to login

Comment: In that case, do a check and don't let the user sign using empty credentials.

Comment: That what I want, what should I use to check it because I tried more things and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to sign in only if the fields, email, and password are not empty, then please use the following lines of code:

```
val email = etEmail.text.toString().trim()
val pass = etPass.text.toString().trim()
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(this) {
        //Your code.
    }
} else {
    Log.d("TAG", "email or pass empty.")
}
```